# What is the semantic difference between "varid", "varsym" in Haskell Report?

Tags: haskell

I am reading the Haskell report 2010 and has some questions with regarding to the meta-logical representation in section 2.4[Here](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4):

1. In the mnemonics of "varid" and "varsym", does "var" mean variable?
2. My understanding are that "varid" are identifiers for variables and functions, while "varsym" are identifiers also, but for operators. Is this understanding correct?
3. If 1 and 2 are correct, does it mean operator is also  a kind of variable? (I am very confused because this is likely not right.)

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: An operator is definitely a kind of variable, except that operators starting with `:` are constructors instead.

Comment: In GHC, however, given appropriate options, this works differently at the type level—operators can be *type constructors*, but not *type variables*. This is sensible because one would rarely want an operator to be a type variable, but one might very well want one to be a type constructor.

Comment: Note that it's perfectly legal to write `let (+) = 5 in (+)*4`, and that `let (+)=5 in 3+4` will produce a type error, rather than a syntax error.

Comment: @dfeuer I thought variable stores data, while operator (a kind of function) maps data. Two different beings, no?

Comment: @dfeuer thanks for the comments. Let me read about the `let` usage first, haven't seen that before.

Comment: No. In Haskell, a function is just a value whose type looks like `a -> b` for some `a` and `b`. Operators are pretty much always bound to functions, because that's what makes them useful, but the letters vs. symbols thing is purely a matter of syntax.

Comment: When you have an operator `+`, what you "really" have is a variable `(+)`, along with magic in the parser that turns `a + b` into `(+) a b`, and similar special rules whose exact details I can't remember for the forms `(a+)` and `(+a)`.

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks a lot for all these comments. I spent some time trying to rectify my understanding of these related concepts: "operator" v.s. "function" v.s. "variable". (with additional questions. ) Now I do agree that operator is a kind of variable. (And we cannot draw equal sign between operator and function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the report is defining the difference between symbols that are used prefix, and those that are used infix, for example:

```
f x y -- f is used prefix

a / b -- / is used infix
```

This is just a syntactic convenience, as all prefix symbols can be used infix with backticks, and all infix symbols can be used prefix with `()`s:

```
x `f` y -- infix

(/) a b -- prefix
(a /) b -- operator section
(/ b) a -- operator section
```

Sub-questions:

1. yes, but I can't figure out any meaningful mnemonic for the `id` and `sym` parts. :(
2. operators are in the realm of Haskell syntax, not its semantics.  They're only used to provide a more convenient syntax for writing some expressions.  As far as I know, if they were removed from Haskell, the only loss would be convenient syntax -- i.e. there's nothing that you need operators for, other than convenient syntax, and you can replace every single use of operators with non-operator symbols.  They are completely identical to variables -- they **are** variables -- but require different syntax for their use.
3. yes, I would agree that operator symbols are variables.  However, the values bound to oerators symbols would not be variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, operator is like function pointer in C that points to the actual function, correct?

Comment: @modeller it's very difficult to correctly define things by analogy. :(  An operator symbol in Haskell doesn't have to be bound to a function.  Try `let (+) = 3 in (+)`.  So really, operator symbols are just variables, with different syntactic requirements.

Comment: @modeller, I think Matt Fenwick's explanation is very good; I just wanted to emphasize that notions like "function pointer" are very far from any common Haskell concept.